# Outputting text from an url that returns JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm more of a backend guy, this javascript stuff is a bit out of my area. I could really use a point in the right direction :)

So I have an URL that, for example, returns this JSON:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 1"}}, 
 {"pk": 2, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 2"}}, 
 {"pk": 3, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 3"}}, 
 {"pk": 4, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 4"}}, 
 {"pk": 5, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 5"}}]
```

I want to write a piece of javascript that I can embed in my HTML that will randomly choose and print one of the "fact"s from the JSON URL.

Comment: Why not do it server-side? Less data to fetch from whatever storage you're using and less data to send over the wire.

Comment: @Morten  - I could do that, but it's not really my problem. I think I'm not highlighting how little I know about javascript... I just need a simple piece of js that outputs text from my JSON (which is from a URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps:

```
var a = '[{"pk": 1, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 1"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 2"}}, {"pk": 3, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 3"}}, {"pk": 4, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 4"}}, {"pk": 5, "model": "didyouknow.fact", "fields": {"fact": "Random fact 5"}}]';
alert(eval(a)[0].model);
```

Here's an example that uses AJAX to call out to a (local) web service:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  success: function(data){
    alert(eval(data).result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Except I can't just set var a = to the JSON - the JSON is from a URL. What I need to know is how to set a variable to the contents of that URL.

Comment: Edited. I don't think you're going to be able to poll remote URLs.

Comment: How does this select one of the facts randomly?  I don't see any randomness in here?

Comment: @jfriend00 Looks like you have the answer to that. I've upvoted you for your answer to the randomness part, feel free to edit my answer to include your additions or leave it at that.

Comment: I ended up having the URL return a single random object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var questionData = JSON.parse(data);
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionData.length);
var randomFact = questionData[randomIndex].fields.fact;
```

Then, what you want to do with the randomFact in your web page is up to you and you haven't provided any info on that for us to help with that.  You could put the fact into an existing element on the page.  You could create new elements on the page where you want them, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` to convert into an array and pick a random element. If you still can't get it to work post your code.

Comment: Can I just pass JSON.parse my URL?